# What is this Java generic operator "x.<y>function(...)" called and what does it do?

Tags: java, android, generics

I'm having a hard time giving this question a proper title, but I've been reading through some source code and found the following snippets of code

```
return new IdpResponse(
    in.<User>readParcelable(User.class.getClassLoader()), // <-- x.<y>function(...)
    in.readString(),
    in.readString(),
    in.readInt() == 1,
    (FirebaseUiException) in.readSerializable(),
    in.<AuthCredential>readParcelable(AuthCredential.class.getClassLoader()) // <-- x.<y>function(...)
);
```

from [https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/.../IdpResponse.java](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/d78e72bf12a7af9a7ae11f167764682b792f9c4b/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/IdpResponse.java#L44-L51)

as well as

```
setResult(Resource.<IdpResponse>forLoading());
```

from [https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/.../SmartLockHandler.java](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/9655063940c40dca18ce63796d4678564880c9e8/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/viewmodel/smartlock/SmartLockHandler.java#L74)

What is this called and what does it do? It looks almost like a cast for the function result.

Comment: it's a function with a template, have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30939425/java-template-function

Comment: Are you familiar with [generic methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html)? With syntax `.<SpecificType>someGenericMethod()` you just explicitly provide specific type which generic type should represent in current method invocation.

Comment: @Pshemo - Thanks, that's it. So like function templates in C++.

Comment: It's commonly called a `type witness`, it's needed when the type inference can't figure out the type on its own.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. As AlbertoSinigaglia and Pshemo both said, the constructs you asked about:

   `in.<User>readParcelable(User.class.getClassLoader()`

   and

   `in.<AuthCredential>readParcelable(AuthCredential.class.getClassLoader()`

are both examples of a ["function with a template"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30939425/java-template-function).

2. You can read more details in Oracle's Java tutorials:

   - [Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html)
     ... and ..
   - [Type Inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)
3. Quoting from the "Type Inference" tutorial:

> *Type inference* is a Java compiler's ability to look at each method invocation and corresponding declaration to determine the type
>   argument (or arguments) that make the invocation applicable.
>
> Consider the following example, BoxDemo, which requires the Box class:
>
> ```
> public class BoxDemo {
>
>   public static <U> void addBox(U u, 
>       java.util.List<Box<U>> boxes) {
>     Box<U> box = new Box<>();
>     box.set(u);
>     boxes.add(box);
>   }
>
>   public static <U> void outputBoxes(java.util.List<Box<U>> boxes) {
>     int counter = 0;
>     for (Box<U> box: boxes) {
>       U boxContents = box.get();
>       System.out.println("Box #" + counter + " contains [" +
>              boxContents.toString() + "]");
>       counter++;
>     }
>   }
>
>   public static void main(String[] args) {
>     java.util.ArrayList<Box<Integer>> listOfIntegerBoxes =
>       new java.util.ArrayList<>();
>     BoxDemo.<Integer>addBox(Integer.valueOf(10), listOfIntegerBoxes);
>     BoxDemo.addBox(Integer.valueOf(20), listOfIntegerBoxes);
>     BoxDemo.addBox(Integer.valueOf(30), listOfIntegerBoxes);
>     BoxDemo.outputBoxes(listOfIntegerBoxes);
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> The generic method addBox defines one type parameter named U.
>   Generally, a Java compiler can infer the type parameters of a generic
>   method call. Consequently, in most cases, you do not have to specify
>   them. For example, to invoke the generic method addBox, you can
>   specify the type parameter with a type witness as follows:
>
> ```
> BoxDemo.<Integer>addBox(Integer.valueOf(10), listOfIntegerBoxes);
> ```
>
> Alternatively, if you omit the type witness,a Java compiler
>   automatically infers (from the method's arguments) that the type
>   parameter is Integer:
>
> ```
> BoxDemo.addBox(Integer.valueOf(20), listOfIntegerBoxes);
> ```

4. Finally, regarding "It looks almost like a cast for the function result.":

> [Java - Generics vs Casting Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401726/java-generics-vs-casting-objects)
>
> The point of generics is *NOT* to allow a class to use different types
>   at the same time.
>
> Generics allow you to *define/restrict* the type used by an instance of
>   an object.
>
> The idea behind generics is to *eliminate* the need to cast.

Comment: *"function with a template"*? No, it's called a [***generic method***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4), not "function", not "template".

Comment: Thank you for providing the terminology used in the Java spec (after all, the OP's question was "what is it called?"). Informally, however, I have no qualms with saying it's *like* a "function template" (as AlbertoSinigaglia called it), or even "subroutine template" (terminoligy free of ANY Java connotations). I *hope* I at least successfully conveyed the *concepts* DanielF was asking about.